# selecting the name of the column as values from different column

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

I have a table that has following columns

- `End_date`.
- `count_all_transactions`.
- `count_timeouts`.
- `request_key`.

Now I need to calculate `percentagetimeout` for two different dates and display them simultaneously. I have built my query.

My query is as follows:

```
Select PercentageTimeout ,
  PerTimeout,
  Transaction
From 
(
  select 
    T.COUNT_ALL_TRANSACTIONS as Total,
    T.END_DATE as DT1,
    T.COUNT_TIMEOUTS as Timeouts,
    round (((T.COUNT_TIMEOUTS / T.COUNT_ALL_TRANSACTIONS) * 100)
             ,2) as PercentageTimeout,
    R.INTERFACE_NAME as Transaction
  from rpt_timeout T, dim_request R
  where
    T.REQUEST_KEY = R.REQUEST_KEY
  AND
    T.END_DATE='27 AUG 2012'
) 
left outer join 
(
  select T1.COUNT_ALL_TRANSACTIONS as Total1,
    T1.END_DATE as DT2,
    T1.COUNT_TIMEOUTS as Timeouts1,
    round (((T1.COUNT_TIMEOUTS / T1.COUNT_ALL_TRANSACTIONS) * 100)
             ,2) as PerTimeout,
    R1.INTERFACE_NAME as Transaction1
  from rpt_timeout T1, dim_request R1
  where T1.REQUEST_KEY = R1.REQUEST_KEY
  AND T1.END_DATE='20 AUG 2012'
) on Transaction = Transaction1;
```

This query is giving me correct result but what I am struggling with is that I need the name of the column as the corresponding END_DATE in that table i.e: 
my output should be like

```
27-AUG-2012   20-AUG-2012  Transaction
0.28          0.1          Qpay 
0.09          0.06         Payment
```

Comment: Can you post the output that your query currently produces so that we get a "feel for the data"?

Comment: My output at present is :PercentageTimeout   PerTimeout  Transaction 0.28          0.1          Qpay  0.09          0.06         Payment                                   What i need is the value of END_DATE column to be displayed as my Column name instead of PercentageTimeout and PerTimeout. I don't know how to achieve that

Comment: i the query i posted i haven't selected end_date but teh values of end_date is 27-AUG-2012 and 20-AUG-2012

Comment: @user1733739 if you need a dynamic pivot solution for Oracle - then you can look [to this link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=3227306)

Comment: @user1733739, how do you decide which two dates to use ? are these constants, parameters or what ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL for this.  Since this is specific to Oracle, that means using PL/SQL to construct a query, and then execute it with the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement.

See the link below...

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Here's some example code; it's not complete and may even be syntactically incorrect (I don't have an Oracle server handy, and haven't worked with Oracle in a little while), just a fragment to give you an idea of what I'm talking about.

```
DECLARE
  query VARCHAR2(4000);
  date1 VARCHAR2(25);
  date2 VARCHAR2(25);
BEGIN
  date1 := '27-AUG-2012';
  date2 := '20-AUG-2012';
  query := 'Select PercentageTimeout as ' || date1 ||
           ', PerTimeout as ' || date2 ||
           ',   Transaction From  <the rest of your query goes here>';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
END;
```

Now you might want to create a cursor instead out of your dynamically constructed query string and iterate through the records; whatever you need to do.  The main point is, if you want to dynamically specify column aliases in a query, you need to dynamically construct that query.